# sencha.vscode-extjs silently fails to run sencha app watch within Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, extjs

Version 1.0.3 of the **Sencha Ext JS extension for Visual Studio Code** (sencha.vscode-extjs)
silently fails to run sencha app watch within Visual Studio Code.

I am expecting **extension.vscode-extjs.startAppWatch** to work as it used to.  In the explorer context menu I would execute this.

I am running the following:

- Sencha Cmd v7.4.0.45 (active license)
- Visual Studio Code version 1.62.1

I noticed that the extension has registered one uncaught exception:

*only absolute urls are supported*

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Downgrade to VSCode 1.61.2 solved it